# как правильно сделать редирект 301 при смене части url

Tags: битрикс, seo, чпу

Раньше ссылки выглядели вот так

```
/catalog/planshety/planshet_asus_zenpad_8_0_16gb_black/
```

сейчас удалили слово `catalog`, теперь они выглядят вот так

```
/planshety/planshet_asus_zenpad_8_0_16gb_black/
```

как мне правильно сделать ридерект 301 что б не потерять в позициях поисковика

вот мой файл `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой блок получается:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^catalog(.*)$ http://www.site.ru$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

site.ru на свой сайт заменить нужно